# attach an existing function to a panel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paint

Good morning guys.
I am working with Netbeans IDE and I created a `Jpanel1` in my `jFrame` just with drag and drop, but no I want to attach to this `Jpanel1` a new function which will be the override of the its paint method.
because if I created it with

```
      jPanel Jpanel1 = new jPanel(){

      }
```

I can override the paint method, but with drag and drop way I don't know how to do

thank you

Comment: even with drag and drop, code is still generated in the background. Find that code and change it as you wish.

Comment: it is some think like this
jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
jPanel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jPanel1.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createBevelBorder(0));
        jPanel1.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(600, 700));
        jPanel1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                jPanel1MousePressed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel1.addMouseMotionListener(new 
and I can't modify this part of code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**First**, you will need to create a `CustomPanel` class extending `JPanel` with `public` modifier and give it the custom name. Then override the `paintComponent(Graphics)` function, put your custom painting code inside this function using the `Graphics g`. For example:

```
    public class CustomPanel extends JPanel{

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
       // custom painting code
    }
}
```

**Now, In NetBeans:**

1. Directly drag the class inside your GUI form and drop it. Just like you drag a panel from the Pallete
2. Or, While the `CustomPanel.java` class tab is selected in NetBeans, go

   ```
   Tools-> Click Add To Pallete -> Select Swing Containers -> click Ok
   ```

   Then, you shold be able to add it to your form from left side form navigation panel as shown in following picture:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `netbeans ide` to make `jFrame` using `drag-and-drop` it automatically generates sources under:

```
private void initComponents() {
     //auto generates code here
}
```

Simply you can fulfill your requirement by right clicking `jPanel` under `Design` tab and going `properties` menu.

For more detail you can refer to [Designing a Swing GUI in NetBeans IDE](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart-gui.html).

**Updated after reading your comment on question:**

- To change backGroundColor :

  Go, **Properties** -> on **background** click on right side [image: click menu] and change color as your wish
- To add border:

  Simply you can do by going `border`
- To set size

  Similarly you can change the value of `preferredSize`
- To add event

  Go `Events` tab of your properties and change as your required.
- And to use components like `textField`, `progressBar` and so on you can drag and drop from **palette** which mostly available on right side of your `jFrame Design` tab.

Comment: but I don't find an evenment or propriety like paint or onpaint in order to redefine this function

Comment: but how about overriding paint(jGraphics g) method??
for others events I know in the Event tab, but no paint there...

Comment: @RiadSaadi I am still not able to get your question. if you want to use `mousePressed` event. **Right Click** of your component and go `Events` -> `Mouse` and clicke `mousePressed` then it will goes to sourse code then you can add your logic for further process. You do not need to `overried` any method netbeans automatically  overrieds or asks if required .

Comment: @RiadSaadi, you haven't still explained you have revoked accepting my answer. This is not about the acceptance, but when you revoked, you should have at least mentioned the reason.

Comment: I am sorry, I will be clair this time, I know how to add events as you are saying to me, and adding an event is an overriding of an abstract  MouseEvent, but if I want to override the method paint, no mouseclicked or mousedown or others, I want to write a code in the paint method like I do for the mouseclicked event

Comment: @RiadSaadi, there is no such option with painting. The best you can do it the solution i have provided :)

Comment: yes @sage I think that it is the only way, even if I want to override it in my principal class(I mean the class of jframe), because it is when I am there (jframe class) that I know what to draw and how, and I want to make all these things to draw in paint method because it is running in a thread